# updating tuple string and how to optimize my code

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have one list like that :

```
  [`('__label__c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c', 0.5), ('__label__96693d45-4dec-4b66-a2e2-621329d64b92', 0.498047)]`
```

I want to replace tuple element string value like this:

'__label__c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c' to 'c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c'

I try this :

```
l = [('__label__c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c', 0.5), ('__label__96693d45-4dec-4b66-a2e2-621329d64b92', 0.498047)]
j = []
for x in l:
    for y in x:
        if type(y) == str:
            z = y.replace('__label__',"")



    j.append((z, x[1]))



print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
[('c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c', 0.5), ('96693d45-4dec-4b66-a2e2-621329d64b92', 0.498047)]
```

how to optimize my code in pythonic way and any other way to update tuple value because  tuple is immutable

Comment: Some form of list comprehension? I've shave half seconds of single functions by using this. I can't test this so I'm sorry if it's wrong `[(z,x[1]) for x in l for y in x if type(y) == str]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, tuples are immutables in Python, but lists are not. So you should be able to update the list `l` in-place.
Moreover, it looks like you already know the position of the element you have to modify and the position of the substring you want to remove, so you can avoid one loop and the `replace` function which will iterate once more over your string.

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    the_tuple = l[i]
    if isinstance(the_tuple[0], str) and the_tuple[0].startswith('__label__'):
        l[i] = (the_tuple[0][len('__label__'):], the_tuple[1])
        # you can also replace "len('__label__')" by "8" to increase performances
        # but I think Python already optimizes it
```

Comment: [len('__label__') - 1 :]  remove  -1  it's work fine  Thank you @gogz

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function:

```
data = [('__label__c091cb93-c737-4a67-95d7-49feecc6456c', 0.5), ('__label__96693d45-4dec-4b66-a2e2-621329d64b92', 0.498047)]
def f(row): return row[0].replace('__label__', ''), row[1]
print(list(map(f, data)))
```